# Typescript debugging works only on local filesystem

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I use webstorm to deploy my webapp. i like to debug on a local or remote html server (http://). the breakpoints only working with local filesystem "file://". is there a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 0.8.2.0 and earlier, this didn't work. Assuming all your .map and .ts files are reachable on the server, you'll be able to do this using the 0.8.3.0 release (should be out sometime tomorrow or Wednesday).